# Find the volume in the first octant using a double integral for $z=xy$, $z=0$, $y=x$, $x=1$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume in the first octant using a double integral for $z=xy$, $z=0$, $y=x$, $x=1$

I found that $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le x$ as the limits of integration.  So I then setup my double integral this way:

$\int^1_0\int^x_0xy\,dy\,dx$, which gave me a solution of $\frac{1}{8}$.  This doesn't seem correct to me because I don't know how to bound the function by $z=0$

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $xy$ is the *height* at each point, so you have bounded $z$ between $0$ and $xy$ quite naturally, by integrating the height of your object over the $xy$-plane. The more thurough way of doing it would, of course, be to calculate the triple integral
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^x\int_0^{xy} 1\, dz\,dy\,dx
$$
but as you might see, the innermost integral $\int_0^{xy} 1\,dz$ evaluates to $xy$, and you're back at the integral that you have.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!   So it looks like I found the volume correctly?

Comment: @inquisitor Yes. And considering you were specifically told to do a _double_ integral, and not a triple integral, my approach would actually not be quite as correct as yours. You can always use that the volume of an object is equal to $\iint f(x, y) dx\,dy$ where $f(x, y)$ is the height of the object above / below the point $(x, y)$

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct. To see the the limits for $z$ you should use a triple integral. This is how it works

$$\eqalign{
  & V = \int\!\!\!\int\!\!\!\int 
 {dV}  = \int_{x = 0}^1 {dx\left( {\int_{y = 0}^x {dy\left( {dz\int_{z = 0}^{xy} 1 } \right)} } \right)}   \cr 
  & \,\,\,\, = \int_{x = 0}^1 {\int_{y = 0}^x {\int_{z = 0}^{xy} {1dzdydx} } }   \cr 
  & \,\,\,\, = \int_{x = 0}^1 {\int_{y = 0}^x {xydydx} }  \cr} $$

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is right , also z = 0 specifies simply the xy region so pieces of xy region taken together along z axis will make a 3d structure and the volume of this structure you are taking in terms of the integral is correct .

P.S  I just wanted to say you need to visualize i.e as z = 0 the xy = 0 this implies x =0 or y = 0 , the points are in xy plane.
I also think this question tries to confuse you but take it straight and simple 
you can google the figure z =xy  , it will help you why you got such answer .

Hope that helps